# Javascript for loop in a select box

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage with a form that contains some input fields and one of these is a listbox. Inside this listbox I have to add (in crescent order) numbers that go from 40000 to 99999 and they increase by 1000 every time.

Example: 40000 - 41000 - 42000 - 43000 ... 97000 - 98000 - 99000 - 99999

I wrote a Javascript function but it's not working. Here you can see the HTML code:

```
<fieldset style="width:500px;">
<legend><font color="#D8D8D8"><b>Required Fields</b></font></legend>
<font color="#FFFFFF"><b>Player's Name</b>:</font> <input type="text" name="nome" />
<font color="#FFFFFF"><b>VRs</b>:</font> <select name="cognome">
</select> <br />
</fieldset>
```

Here there's the javascript function

```
<script>
var i=40000

for(i;i<42000;i=i+1000)
{var select = document.getElementById("cognome");
select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(i, i)}
}
</script>
```

My problem is that any data appear on the listbox. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What  exactly does not working? Have you already taken a view into the error console of your Chrome, Safari or Firefox browser?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I put that script in <body onload="myFunction()"> but when I open the page, I don't see any new option added. I use Firefox 20.0.1

Comment: The `}` on the end of new option is mismatched.

Comment: What happends if you replace the closing curly braces by a normal closing braces at 'new Option(i, i}'?
'

Comment: There's an obvious syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `getElementById` so you need an id:

```
<select id="cognome" name="cognome">
```

Also the syntax error where the parentheses need to match :)

Comment: well spotted - this fixes it

Answer (score 0):

Look at your javascript error console, you misplaced a `}` instead of a `)` , see:

```
select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(i, i}
                              THIS SHOULD BE A ')'-----^
```

Also add the `id` as louisbros comments in other answer..

See [**working demo**](http://tinker.io/94512)

Answer (score 0):

Using the comments above:

- Adding an `id="cognome"`
- Correcting the parens.

There's a JFiddle with it working here:

http://jsfiddle.net/WEd84/